# How can I find the download link of a file downloaded by an application?

Tags: http

I have an application, that manages certain text-to-speech voices, installed on my computer, which has the feature to download and install new voices.
When installing a new voice, it is downloaded as a zip file to some temporary location, which the application then unpacks into the program folder, and then imediately deletes the zip file.
Is there a way for me to somehow monitor the application, or the network, or something, to find the download link used to download the file, so I can store it for later?
I am quite sure the application doesn't use urls that expire after use. It should just be a completely normal link to a zip file on some server on the internet.
I don't know anything about http monitoring or programming or anything, so I'm just looking for a simple way to do this.

I believe that the voices are downloaded as zip files for two reasons:
Firstly, I tried searching for the voice name on the roth of my hard drive, while it was downloading, and it showed up as a zip file in some temporary folder, but disappeared as soon as the voice was installed.
Secondly, the Mac version actually save the zip file in the Downloads folder without deleting it, but since those are for mac, they are of no use to me.

Also, I don't think there's any intent to keep the user from keeping the zip file, it is just a streamlined way of installing new voices.

Comment: Vague and likely unanswerable. *an application installed on my computer* could be anything. Very likely NOT possible (and why one would do it anyway?) if the software has been competently coded and their intent is to obfuscate the process. *t should just be a completely normal link to a zip file on some server on the internet* Maybe but, again, if properly coded it won't allow downloading by anything or any means except when authenticated by the app itself.  I also wander how exactly did you found out *it is downloaded as a zip file*...

Comment: It may or may not matter. Anyway, please [edit] the question to add new info, not just comments.

Comment: If you are clever, you can use the [system internals process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see ALL of this. The difficult thing with this application is that is sees EVERYTHING and you need to create filters to narrow down only the thing you care about.  Also, your tag `http` has nothing to do with anything.  1 filter will include ONLY things at are that app.. if there is too much information, add another filter for PATHs that include .zip.. etc etc.

Comment: What is wireshark (for windows)? What is Process Monitor (sysinternals)?

Comment: What is your end goal, what are you actually trying to accomplish? What is the underlying reason why you are trying to find this URL or capture the downloaded file?

Comment: I want to find the link, so I can download and store the file for later use. The program has an option for installing a voice from an already downloaded file, and I have another computer at work with bad internet connection, where I might need to install more voices. Secondly, when installing the voices, all files from the archive are given the current time stamp, insteat of the timestamp for their original creation. I am very interested in being able to unpack the zip file myself, so I can see when the files were originally created.

Comment: Ok, I have now aparently captured the data. It somehow captured all the content of the zip file, but I don't know what I do from here to try and find the link.

Answer (score 1):

With the small about of information you've given, I can only give broad suggestions, but these should hopefully point you in the right direction.

You'll need to use *some* sort of inspection tool to do this. Three that *may* work are (in order of likely simplicity):

1. [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (by SysInternals/Microsoft): This is TaskManager on steroids and allows you to see both processes AND sub-processes, as well as the arguments they're run using. Download that run the tool, identify the running process of this application you want to inspect, initiate the voice download, and then look at any sub-processes the application may have spawned (in default view processes are listed in a tree, so you'll just look at any processes treed off of this main application process). Hold your mouse over this sub-process and see if it shows the URL the application is accessing.
2. [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (also by SysInternals/Microsoft): This is perhaps a more advanced version of ProcessExplorer and can see and show individual actions by processes. If ProcessExplorer doesn't show the URL being accesses, try using ProcessMonitor to inspect activity on your system by this application or its sub-processes.
3. [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/): This is a network communication inspection tool. If the other applications don't show you want you need, you can use WireShark to inspect all of the network traffic for your system, filtering it down to traffic generated by this application. If the application encrypts its communication you may be out of luck, though if you're able to access the application's security certificate, you may be able to decrypt and inspect the traffic.

Both ProcessMonitor and WireShark can log the data captured, meaning that you can begin capturing in these, run the application and download a voice, then stop the capture and review the data captured at your leisure, whereas ProcessExplorer is more about telling you what is happening on your system NOW and has limited, if any, capture capabilities.

Comment: Thank you, but none of them works for me. When I, for example, run WireShark and select capture, then downlload a voice, and then stop the capture, it says that nothing was captured. What am I doing wrong?